# Printing Simple message in Python

Tags: python, windows, printf, ctypes

I have installed Python 2.7.3 and PyScripter.
When I'm trying to run this simple code, the interupter doesn't show anything:

```
from ctypes import *
msvcrt = cdll.msvcrt
message_string = "Hello world!\n"
msvcrt.printf("Testing: %s".encode('ascii'), message_string.encode('ascii')
```

(tried also without the encoding)

Comment: You've missed an end bracket `)` for your `printf` function. Or was this a formatting mistake?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This was a formatting mistake, sorry.

Comment: What do you get for `import sys; print type(sys.stdout)`?

Comment: >>> 
<class '__main__.AsyncStream'>
>>>

Comment: To use `printf` you need a Win32 console that has the standard `FILE` streams.

Comment: Thanks, but what does it mean ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me in the interactive shell:

```
>>> msvcrt.printf("Testing: %s".encode('ascii'), message_string.encode('ascii'))

Testing: Hello World!
22
```

Try putting it in an .py file and then run from cmd

```
python C:\path\to\file
```

Comment: It's working with the interactive shell but not with the PyScripter. 
There is not way to make it work in the program ?

Comment: @Shpongle: BTW, why don't you just try `print "Testing: %s" % message_string` ?

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So if I want to test crt functions, this can only be done by the Win32 Console ?

Comment: @Shpongle: You can use PyScripter's run->external run. This runs the script in another process with standard streams piped. The default options capture stdout. But it's simpler to just run a script through Explorer or the cmd shell.